# How to access dimensions from android and apply it to style in react native

Tags: font-size, react-native, native-module

I am developing a hybrid app react native + Android. I want consistent font size throughout the app. So I want to access the font size declared in dimen.xml of Android, where I have created stubs for different dimensions of different devices. I can expose it via Native Modules like this

```
@ReactMethod
public float getFontSize(Callback callback){
    callback.invoke(mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_h1));
    return mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_h1);
}
```

and I can access it from react native like this

```
NativeModules.Utilities.getFontSize((textsize)=>console.log(textsize))
```

But then How can I add it to my following style?

```
TextStyleH1: {
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        fontFamily: "PFEncoreSansPro-Book",
      },
      android: {
        fontFamily: "pfencoresanspro_book",
      },
    }),
    fontSize: 18, // I want to change to textsize returned from NativeModule
  },
```

### Clarification

My styles are defined in styles.js which has

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   ...
});
```

because I want it to be reusable as I have 14 diff styles of text and have lot of `<Text />` in my components. So I want to change the fontSize inside styles.js only (if possible)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add it by appending style:

```js
componentWillMount() {        
    NativeModules.Utilities.getFontSize((textsize)=>this.setState({textsize}));
}

render() {
    return (
        <Text style={[styles.TextStyleH1, {
            fontSize: this.state.textsize
        }]}>
            Sample Text
        </Text>
    );
}
```

Comment: But in this case, I will have to do this every time I render the <Text />. I don't want to do it as I want to keep my styles separate and reusable

Comment: Also, I have 14 diff sizes of fonts. If I use your method then I will have 14 states in every component just for textSize

Comment: @RajSuvariya Your styles are already separate and reusable -- except of the `fontSize` part. it's a dynamic value.

Comment: Yes but isn't there any way to change fontsize inside my styles.js file?

Comment: If you have so many different size of fonts, I suggest to fetch everything from `NativeModules` inside of a separate static class.

Comment: when you call `StyleSheet.create`, react-native will compact them into immutable values. you can see them by `console.log(styles.textstyle)` -- will show something like `_11` `_22`

Comment: I want to fetch fontsize from NativeModule but How can I then change the styles defined in styles.js because as  you said they are immutable

Comment: by *appending style* --- because you can never change an immutable value. please have a look on my answer again =)

Comment: Bro I got it but that is not the correct way as I need to override every time I use the style. Anyway, I figured out other way and I am gonna post the answer very soon.

Comment: good to know you solved your problem =) share what you found please, so we can learn and advance from a better answer.